# How to ignore dll files in tfs after exclusion?

Tags: version-control, tfs

I have got 8 projects.
Projects referencing each other.
I exclude all dll files of my own projects from sourcecontrol

**But every build the dlls gets changed and tfs enters into the conflict mode.**

I want to avoid it.

is that possible ? And how ?

Thanks

PS: Tomorrow is my birthday this would be a great present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete those DLL's from TFS source control. Probably they are checked in once and now TFS will try to update them constantly when they change.

Comment: Thanks... I forgot to delete from tfs source control explorer... and they are probably checked in once...